# Is there a setting to make the green window button use the old default behaviour?

Tags: macos, window-manager, fullscreen

I was wondering if there was a way to make the green window traffic light button default to the old behaviour of maximizing the window instead of making it go into a full screen app.

Currently I have better touch tools making this happen, however it's the only thing I use BTT for and I was wondering if there was some hidden terminal command setting to change the green button behaviours around so cmd-click makes it a full screen app, and normal click maximizes the window.

Can the maximize control in a window be changed natively or with some third party tool or window manager?

Comment: You can set double click title bar to maximise, if that would do as a compromise.

Comment: How averse are you to OS hacking stuff? I'm pretty sure there's a MacForge plugin that does this. (If not I think I'd even be willing to compile one, I know exactly what the code would be as I wrote a plugin that does the exact opposite on Mavericks.) But, this is proper code injection—you need to disable Apple's System Integrity Protection and leave it off. https://www.macenhance.com/macforge